# Getting all possible key sizes for JCE KeyGenerators

Tags: java, jce

I am writing a web service which will allow a user to pick an algorithm from a list of algorithms and generate a key of a specified size (using KeyGenerator). I can't find any way through the API to get the set of possible key sizes for a specified algorithm. If I try to generate a key that has an invalid size I will get an exception indicating as such, with the possible key sizes for that algorithm in the error message, but I would like to predetermine it for a pick list for the user. Can anyone point me towards the correct API for this, if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is available through API, since some algorithms take ranges instead of distinct values.

From [Java Cryptography Architecture Documentation (Java 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider), Section *Keysize Restrictions*, *KeyGenerator*:

> The SunJCE provider uses the following default keysizes (in bits) and enforces the following restrictions:

```
KeyGenerator
╔══════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   Algorithm Name     ║ Default Keysize  ║                             Restrictions/Comments                              ║
╠══════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ AES                  ║             128  ║ Keysize must be equal to 128, 192, or 256.                                     ║
║ ARCFOUR (RC4)        ║             128  ║ Keysize must range between 40 and 1024 (inclusive).                            ║
║ Blowfish             ║             128  ║ Keysize must be a multiple of 8, ranging from 32 to 448 (inclusive).           ║
║ DES                  ║              56  ║ Keysize must be equal to 56.                                                   ║
║ DESede (Triple DES)  ║             168  ║ Keysize must be equal to 112 or 168.                                           ║
║                      ║                  ║ A keysize of 112 will generate a Triple DES key with 2 intermediate keys, and  ║
║                      ║                  ║ a keysize of 168 will generate a Triple DES key with 3 intermediate keys.      ║
║                      ║                  ║ Due to the "Meet-In-The-Middle" problem, even though 112 or 168 bits of key    ║
║                      ║                  ║ material are used, the effective keysize is 80 or 112 bits respectively.       ║
║ HmacMD5              ║             512  ║ No keysize restriction.                                                        ║
║ HmacSHA1             ║             512  ║ No keysize restriction.                                                        ║
║ HmacSHA256           ║             256  ║ No keysize restriction.                                                        ║
║ HmacSHA384           ║             384  ║ No keysize restriction.                                                        ║
║ HmacSHA512           ║             512  ║ No keysize restriction.                                                        ║
║ RC2                  ║             128  ║ Keysize must range between 40 and 1024 (inclusive).                            ║
╚══════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I suggest you provide a suitable component for user entry (editable combobox) that changes upon algorithm selection and then provide validation for it.